# Running xpc connection outside the main method

Tags: objective-c, macos, xpc, nsxpcconnection

I was wondering if there's any limitation for the context where I initialize my xpc service.

Here's how I currently initialize my xpc service from main() which works just fine.

```
  listener_ = [[NSXPCListener alloc] 
     initWithMachServiceName:@"com.bla.bla"]; 
  xpcService *delegate = [xpcService new];
  listener_.delegate = delegate;
  [listener_ resume];
  [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] run];
```

However, when calling it from different method(main)/thread(main thread)... It doesn't accept remote calls, even though the listener was properly initialized.

I even tried to wrap this code to run on the main thread using the following wrapper

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  listener_ = [[NSXPCListener alloc] 
     initWithMachServiceName:@"com.bla.bla"]; 
  xpcService *delegate = [xpcService new];
  listener_.delegate = delegate;
  [listener_ resume];
}
```

In the example above, the `[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] run];` is called from the main method.

So my question is what are the requirements to make the XPC work.. is it mandatory to call it from the main method ?

Comment: Are `listener_ ` and `delegate` deallocated when they go out of scope?

Comment: This code is called from C++ method in class and the listener_ is a member of this class... the class is singleton so I the lifetime of `lisener_` will remain... as for the `delegate` I guess it lives as long as `listener_` lives since it has reference. is it a good practice ? do i need to use bridge here ?

Comment: `delegate` is a weak reference.

Comment: you're right. so If i declare delegate as a class member, it should last beyond the scope of this function. right?

Comment: Yes, or make it a singleton.

Comment: Have you tried `[NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop run]` instead?